# Google Kick Start 2020 Round C: Stable Wall. Always WA but can't find the problem

Tags: python, topological-sort

Problem Statement:

Problem
Apollo is playing a game involving polyominos. A polyomino is a shape made by joining together one or more squares edge to edge to form a single connected shape. The game involves combining N polyominos into a single rectangular shape without any holes. Each polyomino is labeled with a unique character from A to Z.

Apollo has finished the game and created a rectangular wall containing R rows and C columns. He took a picture and sent it to his friend Selene. Selene likes pictures of walls, but she likes them even more if they are stable walls. A wall is stable if it can be created by adding polyominos one at a time to the wall so that each polyomino is always supported. A polyomino is supported if each of its squares is either on the ground, or has another square below it.

Apollo would like to check if his wall is stable and if it is, prove that fact to Selene by telling her the order in which he added the polyominos.

Input
The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a line containing the two integers R and C. Then, R lines follow, describing the wall from top to bottom. Each line contains a string of C uppercase characters from A to Z, describing that row of the wall.

Output
For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is a string of N uppercase characters, describing the order in which he built them. If there is more than one such order, output any of them. If the wall is not stable, output -1 instead.

Limits
Time limit: 20 seconds per test set.
Memory limit: 1GB.
1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
1 ≤ R ≤ 30.
1 ≤ C ≤ 30.
No two polyominos will be labeled with the same letter.
The input is guaranteed to be valid according to the rules described in the statement.

Test set 1
1 ≤ N ≤ 5.

Test set 2
1 ≤ N ≤ 26.

Sample

Input

Output

4
4 6
ZOAAMM
ZOAOMM
ZOOOOM
ZZZZOM
4 4
XXOO
XFFO
XFXO
XXXO
5 3
XXX
XPX
XXX
XJX
XXX
3 10
AAABBCCDDE
AABBCCDDEE
AABBCCDDEE

Case #1: ZOAM
Case #2: -1
Case #3: -1
Case #4: EDCBA

In sample case #1, note that ZOMA is another possible answer.

In sample case #2 and sample case #3, the wall is not stable, so the answer is -1.

In sample case #4, the only possible answer is EDCBA.

Syntax pre-check
Show Test Input

My Code:

```
class Case:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr

    def solve(self):
        n = len(self.arr)
        if n == 1:
            return ''.join(self.arr[0])
        m = len(self.arr[0])
        dep = {}
        used = set() # to save letters already used
        res = []

        for i in range(n-1):
            for j in range(m):
                # each letter depends on the letter below it
                if self.arr[i][j] not in dep:
                    dep[self.arr[i][j]] = set()
                # only add dependency besides itself
                if self.arr[i+1][j] != self.arr[i][j]:
                    dep[self.arr[i][j]].add(self.arr[i+1][j])
        for j in range(m):
            if self.arr[n-1][j] not in dep:
                dep[self.arr[n-1][j]] = set()
        # always find and desert the letters with all dependencies met
        while len(dep) > 0:
            # count how many letters are used in this round, if none is used, return -1
            count = 0
            next_dep = {}
            for letter in dep:
                if len(dep[letter]) == 0:
                    used.add(letter)
                    count += 1
                    res.append(letter)
                else:
                    all_used = True
                    for neigh in dep[letter]:
                        if neigh not in used:
                            all_used = False
                            break
                    if all_used:
                        used.add(letter)
                        count += 1
                        res.append(letter)
                    else:
                        next_dep[letter] = dep[letter]
            dep = next_dep
            if count == 0:
                return -1
        if count == 0:
                return -1
        return ''.join(res)

t = int(input())
for i in range(1, t + 1): 
    R, C = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
    arr = []
    for j in range(R):
        arr.append([c for c in input()])
    case = Case(arr)
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(i,case.solve()))
```

My code successfully passes all sample cases I can think of, but still keeps getting WA when submitted. Can anyone spot what is wrong with my solution? Thanks

Comment: Hi James, welcome to SO. You might want to consider posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. I refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/754509

Comment: @jarrettyeo : No, Code Review is for code that works, but for which the asker wants Feedback. The provided code isn't working yet for some corner case checked by the submission process. James: Can you think of more sample cases not provided by the problem? Could be with invalid input strings that you must survive to, or weird conditions.

Comment: @jarrettyeo, MrBrushy, Thanks for the comments, but I have already tried all cases I can think of. Plus, the logic seems pretty straightforward, so I really don't know why this doesn't work.